# Google Analytics show nothing for all reports under Search Engine Optimizations for the last 2 days

Tags: google, analytics, data

Noted that my GA results under Search Engine Optimization (i.e. queries, geo summary and landing pages) for a client accounts have started showing zero results since June 21st. Can anyone provide a heads up as to why this is happening?

Comment: Is their Webmaster Center account still linked to the GA account?

Comment: Yep - this is going on across a few client accounts. All have web master accounts still linked to them.

Comment: Check that reporting wasn't disabled by mistake `You can disable SEO reporting for selected profiles by clicking the Enable Profiles button and deselecting checkboxes next to the profiles you want to disable. Click Apply to save changes.`

Comment: Hi again Anagio - checked this on two of the account and all is as it should be. Really stamped - so any other ideas would be more than welcome. Cheers.

Comment: Is data being gathered in both GA and Webmaster Tools? Could the site verification file, meta tag, or DNS entry for Webmaster Tools been removed. I'm not sure if that would affect it.

Answer (score 1):

The Search Engine Optimization report pulls in data from the Google Webmaster Tools APIs; they don't involve data that Google Analytics itself collects.

Typically, externally imported results (like Adwords API data) typically face a 24-48 hour lag at minimum; occasionally, that lag can be a little longer. But, "0" results" basically just means that the import for that day hasn't happened yet (FWIW, my accounts haven't gotten their 6/21/2012 imports yet either).